# Custom border element with break in top

Tags: html, css, border

I am trying to create an element in html and css for a website which has a custom border such that it is exactly like the image shown below.  Thereby the element has a border that encompasses all sides with a break in the centre of the top-line and a letter of text centred in this break.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Mockup of custom element with break in the top border]

Comment: I am assuming that you havent tried anything so far and you are just waiting for somebody to code it for you? SO is not a free coding service, first try solve the problem yourself, and when you face an issue then post a question about it. Thanks!

Comment: you should put an element with absolute position over the background element.

Answer (score 1):

Just set your letter in `position:absolute` with background-color;

```css
#text
{
  width:300px;
  border:1px solid black;
  position:relative;
  padding:30px;
  margin-top:30px;

}

#letter
{
  position:absolute;
  top:-40px;
  font-size:30px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:white;
  left:140px;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="text">
<article>
Wikipedia was launched on January 15, 2001, by Jimmy Wales and Larry Sanger.[11] Sanger coined its name,[12][13] a portmanteau of wiki[notes 4] and encyclopedia. There was only the English-language version initially, but it quickly developed similar versions in other languages, which differ in content and in editing practices
</article>
<div id="letter">B</div>
</div>
```

An other possibility without background but with display:flex.

The div with `id=all` is not important, I set it to have a background.

```css
#all
{
 background: linear-gradient(to right,#EB9A7F,#9AEB7F,#7FD0EB,#D07FEB); 
 background-size: cover;
 height:auto;
 padding:10px;
}

#text
{
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   position:relative;
    

}

#text #letter
{
  position:relative;
  top:-1.5em;
  font-size:2em;
  padding:1em;
}

#left,#right
{
  flex:1;
  border-top:1px solid black;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#left
{
  border-left:1px solid black;
}

#right
{
  border-right:1px solid black;
}

article
{
  border:1px solid black;
  border-top:0px solid;
  padding:20px;
}
#top
{
  height:0px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
```

```html
<div id="all">

<div id="text">
<div id="top">

  <div id="left">

  </div>
  <div id="letter">B</div>
  <div id="right">

  </div>
</div>
<article>
Wikipedia was launched on January 15, 2001, by Jimmy Wales and Larry Sanger.[11] Sanger coined its name,[12][13] a portmanteau of wiki[notes 4] and encyclopedia. There was only the English-language version initially, but it quickly developed similar versions in other languages, which differ in content and in editing practices
</article>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: My background is currently not a solid colour.  Is there any way to do this when the background is an image and therefore one cannot just match the background colours?

Comment: Yes I made it !!! https://jsfiddle.net/tjiho/etgs2xxq/2/

Comment: I edit my post and I add this other version with some improvements

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 1em;
  border: thin solid blue;
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  content: "A";
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vel nibh vel nisl mattis convallis quis ultrices lorem. Duis eget molestie enim. Fusce luctus, lorem iaculis faucibus pretium, enim erat iaculis nunc, sed bibendum ipsum felis in leo. Pellentesque
  at aliquet erat. Phasellus imperdiet fermentum placerat.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `div` always has the same background, you can add your letter in `::before` / `::after` pseudo-element with solid background so it covers the border. I've also added the border in pseudo-element so it's "inside" the box, but it could be just a regular border if your box background is the same as your page background.

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/norin89/s10tap73/1/